# Converting LATEX to mathematical symbols in android like math.stackexchange.com

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database, latex, mathematical-expressions

I am building an app which will include questions from physics,mathematics and chemistry.So it is bound to have symbols which are often used in those subjects.I am exactly needing what math.stackexchange.com is using i.e. showing mathematical symbols inline with text and that too put up so neatly.

What I have tried till now: I have tried to use

> https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/formulas

I get the mathematical symbols in form of png images using the API shown in link above but the problem I am getting after getting the image as bitmap in my app is that I don't know how to put that image neatly inline with the surrounding  text like math.stackexchange.com does it.
More information about my app:I am using Firebase as the database for my app,so each question is in the form of JSON object where there are key value pairs for problem and multiple options and correct option.My app only lets the user read from the database.
What I want to know:How exactly can I read the data from my database in such a way that mathematical symbols are perfectly inline with surrounding text as neatly as math.stackexchange.com does it?

Comment: Have you considered [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/)? This is what MathSE is using.

Comment: @nick I got to know that math.stackexchange.com uses MathJax,MathJax uses javascript and till know using the little knowledge that I have android,I will have to use webview but in my app I will be having textviews and radiobutton for problems and multiple options(where I need to convert LATEX to math symbols).Is there a way to get data from webview to textviews and radio button?

Comment: @nick also I am receiving data from Firebase and not some URL.

Comment: @KartikWatwani have you done with this app . if , then tell me how did you fix this problem ?

Comment: @xaif Yes, I was able to solve this problem by using MathJax library with a webview and while I was solving this problem I found a MathJaxView which extended the WebView to show the formatted text.